# Get routing requirement variable in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, yaml

in order to create a navigation for me webinterface I'd like to get a variable from the routing config of my bundle. I define the available pages in **mybundle/Resources/config/routing.yml**.

```
mybundle_homepage:
  pattern:  /{_locale}/{branch}/{page}
  defaults: { _controller: mybundle:mycontroller:index, _locale: de, branch: x.x.x, page: start }
  requirements:
    _locale:  de|en
    page:     start|functions|events|constants|styleguide
```

Now I had a look at the Symfony2 YAML Parser and I have to provide a filepath to it's static method *parse*: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/YAML.html

**mycontroller.php**

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;

class mycontroller extends Controller
{
  public function indexAction($_locale, $branch, $page)
  {
    $routing = Yaml::parse('../Resources/config/routing.yml');
    var_dump($routing);
  }
}
```

I thought I could do it that way because the folder hirarchy looks like that:

> - mybundle
>
>   - Controller
>
>     - mycontroller.php
>   - Rescources
>
>     - config
>
>       - routing.yml

But it's not working. Any ideas or maybe another way to get the requirements.page array from the routing file?

Regards, Ben

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to access the **router** service inside a class that's DI container aware. So, you can write something like:

```
$routes = $this->container->get('router')->getRouteCollection();

$route = $routes->get('my_route_name');
print_r($route->getRequirements());
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you! The routing container is called router not route. :)

Comment: May I ask waht are you trying to achieve? Getting a route's requirements seems a bit strange to me.

Comment: I'd like to create a navigation bar on top of the available pages

Comment: Well, instead of building your own, I'd suggest having a look at [KnpMenuBundle](http://symfony2bundles.org/knplabs/KnpMenuBundle). It does its job very, very well.

Comment: Cheers, I'll have a look at the bundle.

Comment: Be aware that this will not use any cache, so the router will load all your routes each time you call `getRouteCollection()`

Comment: yes this method getRouteCollection() is quite greedy ! I am looking for a method for just getting a route object from its name.